# Removing duplicate lines with sed in batch

Tags: batch-file, sed

I'm working on cleaning up a few hundred files on a Windows machine and one of things I need done to them is removing some duplicate lines. So an example file might look like this:

```
foo=false    
bar=true
baz=false
baz=false
baz=false
```

So in working with `sed` I came across [this site](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/11/unix-sed-tutorial-multi-line-file-operation-with-6-practical-examples/) that showcased a line that removes duplicate lines.

```
sed "$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D" textfile.txt
```

So I went and plugged it into a command window to see if it works and the console window showed the duplicate lines removed. After that I plugged that line into my batch script to run it against my list of files that needed to be edited.

```
FOR /F %%a IN ('listfile.txt') DO (
  sed "$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D" %%a
)
```

But when I ran this against my test list of files it removed every line from the file except for one of the duplicate lines.

I'm not familiar with `sed` enough to know for sure what all the stuff that line is doing but my test of it showed it doing what I wanted. So what gives? Am I missing something in the way `sed` works in a batch file?

---

Based on the comments I tried:

```
gawk "!a[$0]++" textfile.txt
```

and once again it works on the command line but not in the script. So there is definitely some issue with the way the batch file is running this command but I'm unable to figure out what that is.

Comment: nice to see sed in windows batch.... no experience about that, good luck. btw, if you have awk available, do `awk '!a[$0]++'` will remove duplicates..

Comment: I don't know what that is but if it solves my actual issue I wouldn't be against it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler maybe because duplicates are not always adjacent?

Comment: @MatthewGreen give it (the awk line) a try.

Comment: @Kent It doesn't look like this machine has `awk` as an option. It was worth a shot though.

Comment: I know windows based commands want their arguments surrounded by dbl-quotes, but that could be causing sed a problem. See you can run the single line test using single-quotes to surround the `sed` 'program' instead. The awk is definitely "the" solution. Are you using cygwin or mingw or ? to get access to sed? Good luck.

Comment: @MatthewGreen then good luck.. I am not familiar with Win OS. I thought you have sed you have awk too (gnu utilities ...)

Comment: @Kent: if the duplicates are not adjacent, I don't see how you're going to solve the problem with `sed`.  Obviously, `awk` is a candidate in the abstract; that would solve it if it is available.

Comment: @Kent I just found that we have `gawk`. I'm assuming that's close enough but when run in the batch file I get `gawk: cmd. line:1: ^ backslash not last character on line`. However, it does work on the command line much like the `sed` I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more testing on the original `sed` statement I found that it was getting hung up on the `!` in the command. So I started some digging along that route and found that `EnableDelyedExpansion` was causing the `!` and everything between them to be removed even within the `sed` statement.

So my options were to escape the `!` or narrow the scope of the `EnableDelayedExpansion`. Since escaping didn't seem to be working I just narrowed the scope to right around the specific variable that needed it and then the `sed` statement seemed to work correctly after that.

Answer (score 1):

On the Windows platform, it is straightforward using PowerShell:

```
get-content "textfile.txt" | sort-object -unique
```

Bill

Comment: This particular machine is a Windows server 2003 so it doesn't have powershell so this doesn't help solve my issue. But a handful of the others I work on do have powershell so I'll keep this snippet in mind.

Comment: PowerShell is available for Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 1):

For removing duplicates lines with sed, consider the code below. Note that heading and trailing lines will be disregarded and removed in the output.

```
#  make a initial mark in order to work for second line
#+ duplicated case with a simple regex
1{ x; s/^/\n/; x; }
# trimming
s/^\s*//
s/\s*$//
# main
H
x
s/\(\n.*\)\(\n.*\)*\1$/\1\2/
x
# print hold space at the end
$bItsOver
d
:ItsOver
x;
s/^\n*//
s/\n*$//
```